# Can I store pointer to __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ for later use or do I need to copy the string immediately?

Tags: c, gcc, scope, lifetime

What is the lifetime of the string `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` produces?

I know `__func__` generates equivalent of `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`, Thanks to that `static`, if I want to create a record of something that happened in the function somewhere for referencing later, I can just store the value of `__func__` in a `const char*` field in the record and retrieve it whenever I want, long after I left the scope of the function.

Does `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` behave the same way, or does the string it generates behave as a local, temporary value? Say, will this work reliably, or can it fail, fname pointing to a location where the function name used to be, and I need to do make a buffer and do `strncpy()` or similar instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char* fname = NULL;

void foo()
{
    fname = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    printf(fname);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three constants, `__func__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, behave the same way. The [GCC Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) states:

> GCC provides three magic constants that hold the name of the current function as a string. In C++11 and later modes, all three are treated as constant expressions and can be used in constexpr contexts.